# Programming a Latin Square in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I'm trying to make a Latin Square program that accepts a user-entered size of  square (e.g. entering 5 will generate a Latin Square 5x5) and then output the formatted square to the user.

If you don't know what a Latin Square is or want to see the actual task I have been set, [look no further](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qqSc.jpg).

I have slightly coded some of this, but I'm failing at the first hurdle. Teachers are providing no help, you lot are my only hope.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  // Variables

  // 2D array, size defined in main code
  Square: array of array of integer;
  // Integer holding the square size
  SquareSize: integer;

begin
  // Introduction
  writeln('This program will generate a Latin Squar of a size designated by you.');
  // Ask for user input, receive and store in a variable
  write('Enter the size of the Latin Square (1 value): ');
  readln(SquareSize);
  // More user friendly garbage
  writeln('Latin Square size: ', SquareSize, ' x ', SquareSize, '.');

  // Calculations

  // Set size of the 2D array to user designated dimensions
  setlength(Square, SquareSize, SquareSize);

end.
```

After the last line of code (setlength) I want to set ALL values in my new 2D array to the user-entered number. I think.

Other than that, **I have no clue what I'm doing.**

If you want to help me, please can you try to keep it as simple as possible so I can understand it?

Sorry for any screw-ups made in this, first time on Stack Overflow.

Comment: `for y := 0 to High(Square) do FillChar(Square[y], Lenght(Square[y]), SomeValue);`

Comment: Hey Victoria, how would I output this/finish the program. I kinda understand what this code does up to SomeValue. What would I put in as SomeValue: SquareSize, or some other number?

Comment: @Victoria: what does that do? It certainly doesn't generate a magic square. It doesn't even fill one row, since `Length` should be multiplied by `SizeOf(Integer)` to get the number of bytes in a row. And apart from `0`, what could `SomeValue` be? Note that dynarrays are zero-filled by `SetLength` anyway.

Comment: @Rudy, I was thinking that the OP wants to initialize the whole array with the given value (`SomeValue`).

Comment: Personally I'd fill square[y][0] and not square[y] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qqSc.jpg) you gave also gives the answer, see below the code.

```
program LatinSquare;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type 
  TSquare = array of array of Integer;

procedure WriteLatinSquare(var Square: TSquare; N: Integer);
var
  X, Y: Integer;
begin
  { Allocate and fill the square array. }
  SetLength(Square, N, N);
  for Y := 0 to High(Square) do
    for X := 0 to High(Square[Y]) do
      Square[X, Y] := (Y + X) mod N + 1;

  { Display the Square array. }
  for Y := 0 to High(Square) do
  begin
    for X := 0 to High(Square[Y]) do
      Write(Square[X, Y]:3);
    Writeln;
  end;
  Writeln;
end;

var
  Square: TSquare;
  SquareSize: Integer;

begin
  SquareSize := 6;
  WriteLatinSquare(Square, SquareSize);
  Readln;
end.
```

As the link says: start with `1 2 3 4 5 6`, then the next line, shift by one, so that becomes `2 3 4 5 6 1`, etc... That is what the first part (with the `X`, `Y` loops) does: it fills the square.

Of course, `Y + X` can go over the limit of `0..5` (I add the `1` later on), so you use `mod` to wrap the values around, so `6` becomes `0`, `7` becomes `1`, etc. In effect:

```
1st line: 0+0=0 -> 0, 0+1=1 -> 1, 0+2=2 -> 2, 0+3=3 -> 3, 0+4=4 -> 4, 0+5=5 -> 5
2nd line: 1+0=1 -> 1, 1+1=2 -> 2, 1+2=3 -> 3, 1+3=4 -> 4, 1+4=5 -> 5, 1+5=6 -> 0
3rd line: 2+0=2 -> 2, 2+1=3 -> 3, 2+2=4 -> 4, 2+3=5 -> 5, 2+4=6 -> 0, 2+5=7 -> 1
etc...
```

Then you add the 1, so instead of `0 1 2 3 4 5`you get `1 2 3 4 5 6`.

The second part of the routine just prints the `Square` array.

If you don't need to save the square, it can be done in one part:

```
procedure WriteMagicSquare2(N: Integer);
var
  X, Y: Integer;
begin
  for Y := 0 to N - 1 do
  begin
    for X := 0 to N - 1 do
      Write((Y + X) mod N + 1, ' ');
    Writeln;
  end;
  Writeln;
end;
```

Output (for N = 6):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 1
3 4 5 6 1 2
4 5 6 1 2 3
5 6 1 2 3 4
6 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: When I try to use this, I get an error on the WriteMagicSquare(6). `[dcc32 Error] ProjectName.dpr(34): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical`

Comment: Also, may I ask, as I'm at a beginners level, could you quickly run through what

  try
    WriteMagicSquare(6);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message); 

means in simple terms? Also, what is the difference between type and var?

Comment: @iHaveNoIdeaWhatImDoing: That's what you get for modifying the code on the spot. ;-) I'll update the code. The `try..except` part does exception handling. It is generated automatically in newer versions of Delphi. You can actually omit it. I will remove it.

Comment: You should *know* the difference between `type` and `var`. The former declares a type (starts a type section), in which I declare the type of the Square. the second starts a var section, e.g. for X and Y in the procedure and for Square in the program. The type of X and Y is Integer, the type of Square is TSquare (as declared near the top).

Comment: FWIW, [Object Pascal Language Guide](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/cbuilder6/EN/CB6_ObjPascalLangGuide_EN.pdf). See page 4-16: Declarations and 5-1: Data types, variables and constants.Instead of using built-in types like Integer, you can also define your own types, like TSquare.

Comment: @iHaveNoIdeaWhatImDoing: ***get an idea what you are doing***. I assume this is homework, so probably, I already "helped" you too much. You don't learn anything that way. Read the chapters I mentioned and learn. Won't take long. Next lesson, you can then surprise your teacher with your knowledge.

Comment: I will do! Honestly, I was looking for a good manual on all of this, so you linking official Delphi documents really helped. Don't worry about helping me "too much", I had already tried everything up to this point and nothing had worked. I'll read up and use it as good revision material :)

Comment: Also, to get user inputs working: Should I just do a readln like I have done originally, and feed that in at the end?

Comment: Put it before the call to WriteMagicSquare in the final `begin..end.` section (the main program).

Comment: Alright. As a noob to Stack Overflow, how do I close this question?

Comment: You already "closed" it by accepting it. All is well. I modified the code a little to show where you should add (most of) the code you already had.

Comment: Oh yeah, also, I don't wanna be a pain, but you don't have to modify the code, as I expect all my other classmates may find this thread and just copy/paste yours in. I know how to implement the user inputs, so if you wanna roll it back to when it was always 6, be my guest. You don't have to though. (Also, thanks for the help again, I'mma stop posting and extending these comments, woops)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your in my school given this is the exact homework I have from the same book word for word. On note of the code above I will add one point, the Latin squares size should be user entered so in the last block of code change it to this:

```
  var
  Square: TSquare;
  X, UserI, SquareSize: Integer;

begin
  X := 0;
  Writeln('type -1000 to stop the loop');
  repeat
    Writeln('What size square do you want?');
    readln(UserI);
    if UserI = -1000 then
    begin
      goto gotolable;
    end

    else
      SquareSize := UserI;
    WriteLatinSquare(Square, SquareSize);
    writeln ('Press enter to do another Latin square');
    readln;
  until X = 1;
gotolable:
```

Comment: Hey, I added to the answer try this: var
  Square: TSquare;
  X, UserI, SquareSize: Integer;

begin
  X := 0;
  Writeln('type -1000 to stop the loop');
  repeat
    Writeln('What size square do you want?');
    readln(UserI);
    if UserI = -1000 then
    begin
      goto gotolable;
    end

    else
      SquareSize := UserI;
    WriteLatinSquare(Square, SquareSize);
    writeln ('Press enter to do another Latin square');
    readln;
  until X = 1;
gotolable: